# Windows 8 Batch file issue

Tags: command-line, windows-8, batch

Batch Programming

Hello! I am trying to write a batch program which can delete all files having the same extensions anywhere in my computer location C: and on my desktop. But when it does work.

Here is the first bat file I've done but nothing happen after launching.

```
@echo off
del "C:\*.vsdx" /s /q
```

I have programed another one that I've tested:

```
@echo off
del "H:\*.vsdx" /s /q
del "C: \*.vsdx" /s /q
del "F:\*.vsdx" /s /q
del "Desktop:\*.vsdx" /s /q
```

Concerning this program, after running it I noticed that `.vsdx` files in device H and F disappear. But files in the location `C:` and some others that I've created in `Documents` do not disappear. So I'm asking your help on how to solve this issue.

Summary of problem: I want to write a batch file which can delete all files having the same extension from my computer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this would be:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir C:\Path\to\folder\*.vsdx /s /b') do del %i /f /q
```

In a batch file, use double percent signs instead of one(`%%i`).

`C:\Path\to\folder` is a placeholder for the actual path.

Though cmd isn't very powerful, I recommend you use PowerShell instead.

The PowerShell way:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Path\to\folder" -Force -Recurse -Filter "*.vsdx" | Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do this would be:

```batch-file
@echo off

for %%i in (H,C,F)do echo\ del/s /q /f /a "%%~i:\*.vsdx"
```

---

- Or, in PowerShell:

```batch-file
'H','C','F'|% {ls -re $($_+':\*.vsdx')|Remove-Item -force -WhatIf}
```

---

It has been proposed to use **`echo\`** in **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** and **`-WhatIf`** in **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**, this gives you a preview of the actions, without actually deleting the files.

- To effectively delete files, remove:

```batch-file
@echo off

for %%i in (H,C,F)do echo\ del/s /q /f /a "%%~i:\*.vsdx"
```

```batch-file
'H','C','F'|% {ls -re $($_+':\*.vsdx')|Remove-Item -force -WhatIf}
```

---

**Additional resources /`CMD`:**

- [`Del /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

---

**Additional resources /`PS1`:**

- [`Foreach`](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html)
- [`Remove-Item`](https://ss64.com/ps/remove-item.html)
- [`ForEach-Object|%`](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)